# Mongoose join query using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have two schemas:

Department:

{dept_id :Number, 
name: String,
Member: [type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref :'Professor']

Professor:

{
deptid :{type:Number, ref:Department},
name: String,
age:Number}

I need to find a joined table consisting of employee details along with Department details.

How can i do that?

Comment: try lookup in mongoose.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, in mongoose you don't and sometimes shouldn't follow a relational database model, it's usually better to embed one model inside another